# Erro CORS com SignalR usando UseCredentials()

Tags: c#, react, cors, signalr

Como diz no título, estou com um problema de CORS com as Credentials usando o SignalR, o erro retornado é:

> Access to fetch at `https://localhost:54083/notification/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1` from origin `http://localhost:3000` has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

O meu problema é que eu já adicionei no meu Startup.cs, em `services.AddCors`, o método `AllowCredentials()`, e agora tenho ficado sem muitas opções de como resolver.

Segue meus métodos `ConfigureServices` e `Configure` de `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureCloudFoundryOptions(Configuration);
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
            

            services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ClientPermission", policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
            services.AddSignalR();

            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Key"));

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        // If the request is for our hub...
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            (path.StartsWithSegments("/notification")))
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();


        }
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            

            app.UseCors("ClientPermission");
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notification");

            });

            
            


        }
    }
```

O frontend é em React e é feito o consumo do serviço do SignalR desta forma aqui:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("https://localhost:54083/notification")
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    setConnection(newConnection);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (connection) {
      console.log(connection)
      connection
        .start()
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Connected!");

          connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
            setNotifications(...notifications.push(message));
          });
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log("Connection failed: ", e));
    }
  }, [connection]);
```

Comment: já tentou complementar a política de CORS com o argumento WithMethods? assim:  .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "OPTIONS")

Comment: @M.Bertolazo tentei aqui mas não deu certo. O problema tem a ver com a falta de um valor para Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, não com os métodos que estão sendo enviados.

Comment: Tenta adicionar na política o parâmetro .WithCredentials

Comment: `WithCredentials()` não é mais utilizado, aparentemente.

Answer (score -1):

Foram adicionadas novas politicas nos navegadores para acesso as redes privadas. Neste site https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/ contém mais detalhes sobre essas mudanças.

Enfim, pelo que tudo indica será necessário informar nos cabeçalhos das requisições a política a seguir:

> Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network

Para que a comunicação possa ser estabelecida.